# How do I properly sign a SOAP message with SHA2 in C#?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, sha2

I have the following requirements from a 3rd party service that I'm using

> Transactions dealing with personal information and other sensitive
> data use transport layer security protection. The web service message
> will be transported over https (HTTP over SSL) and must adhere to Web
> Service (WS)-Security v1.1 standard. The WS-Security section of the
> service message must:
>
> - Be signed with x.509 certificate using a 2048 bit key size
> - Use SHA2 with RSA algorithm for encryption
> - Use C14 canonicalization.

I managed to get my message signed with the following code

```
someServiceRef.widjetClient client = null;

try
{
    X509Certificate2 signingCert = GetSigningCert();
    var bindings = new BasicHttpsBinding();
    bindings.Security.Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
    bindings.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate;

    client = new someServiceRef.widjetClient(
        bindings,
        new EndpointAddress(@"<URL OF SERVICE>"));

    client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = signingCert;
    client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = signingCert;

    client.Open();

    var request = BuildRequest();

    var response = client.SayHello(request);

    Console.WriteLine(response);
}
finally
{
    if (client != null)
    {
        if (client.State == System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Faulted)
            client.Abort();
        else
            client.Close();
    }
}
```

The problem is that my message is being signed with sha1 instead of sha2. I'm trying to sign my message properly but the examples I found online have you generate the soap message then manually modify it with XML parsing and adding new nodes. I don't understand these examples and I'm trying to figure out a way to tell the service to do it for me. I have a sample of what the request signature should look like from the 3rd party below. I don't see anything in the client or binding class that would allow me to change things like the signature algorithm. How would I go about doing this?

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1">
            <wsse:BinarySecurityToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="XWSSGID-12324774331131695995061">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
            <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:SignedInfo>
                    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha2" />
                    <ds:Reference URI="#XWSSGID-1232477437326-1352495766">
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha2" />
                        <ds:DigestValue>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                    <ds:Reference URI="#XWSSGID-1232477437326-823787906">
                        <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha2" />
                        <ds:DigestValue>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ds:DigestValue>
                    </ds:Reference>
                </ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:SignatureValue>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ds:SignatureValue>
                <ds:KeyInfo>
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference xmlns:wsse="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsse:Id="XWSSGID-1232477437311698965010">
                        <wsse:Reference URI="#XWSSGID-12324774331131695995061" />
                        <ds:X509Data>
                            <ds:X509IssuerName>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ds:X509IssuerName>
                            <ds:X509SerialNumber>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                        </ds:X509Data>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
            </ds:Signature>
            <wsu:Timestamp xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="XWSSGID-1232477437326-823787906">
                <wsu:Created>2009-01-20T18:50:37.233Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2009-01-20T18:50:42.233Z</wsu:Expires>
            </wsu:Timestamp>
        </wsse:Security>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="XWSSGID-1232477437326-1352495766">
        BODY OF MESSAGE GOES HERE
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Sha2 is 256 SHA.  So use following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha256?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. Where in the creation of the service or binding would I do something like this? The example you posted is just computing the hash of a file

Comment: The default version of sha (sh1 or sha 256) depends on version of Net.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/retargeting/4.5.1-4.7.2

Comment: This may help you:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8b149878-f9a2-44e3-afd4-68884b02e129/algorithm-suite-wcf-ws-security?forum=wcf

Comment: @TheobaldDu yes that was part of it. I figured it out like 2 days ago. I'll post a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working here is the final solution

```
someServiceRef.widjetClient client = null;

try
{
    X509Certificate2 signingCert = GetSigningCert();
    var bindings = new BasicHttpsBinding();
    bindings.Security.Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
    bindings.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate;
    bindings.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.Basic256Sha256

    var elements = bindings.CreateBindingElements();
    elements.Find<SecurityBindingElement>().EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
    var customBindings = new CustomBinding(elements);

    client = new someServiceRef.widjetClient(
        customBindings,
        new EndpointAddress(@"<URL OF SERVICE>"));

    client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = signingCert;
    client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = signingCert;

    client.Open();

    var request = BuildRequest();

    var response = client.SayHello(request);

    Console.WriteLine(response);
}
finally
{
    if (client != null)
    {
        if (client.State == System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Faulted)
            client.Abort();
        else
            client.Close();
    }
}
```