# How to build a client with SOAP Message Security in WCF .NET Framework using RSA-SHA1?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap

I need to call an old IBM Websphere webservice, that requires transport and message security via a couple of certificates.

I have it all working in SoapUI, which sends a SOAP message that signs the body with RSA-SHA1. And we get the correct response back. Yay!

I can't get it work work in code, via a simple c# console app. (.NET Framework)

I'm not sure which type of SecurityBindingElement to use. The closest one to working seems to be provided by SecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateBindingElement().

My code reaches the webservice which responds with a SOAP fault:
ERRO00001 *The Verification Type configuration 'asymmetric' does not allow algorithm 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1'*

I've tried all the DefaultAlgorithmSuites and none produce RSA-SHA1, and it may be because [Microsoft no longer supports SHA1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/announcements/sha-1-signed-content-retired)?

- Can we provide an 'RSA-SHA1' algorithm to WCF?
- Build the soap XML without WCF and use a SignedXML node for the body maybe?
- Is there another way?

Working SOAP (Produced by SoapUI):

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:v1="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Service/V1.1" xmlns:v11="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/Namespace/Common/Core/V1.1">
<soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing">
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-32C491BB4DA90C1EBD165647963666325">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
        <ds:Signature Id="SIG-32C491BB4DA90C1EBD165647963666529" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                    <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsa soap v1 v11" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                </ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                <ds:Reference URI="#id-32C491BB4DA90C1EBD165647963666328">
                    <ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
                            <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="v1 v11" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </ds:Transform>
                    </ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                    <ds:DigestValue>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-32C491BB4DA90C1EBD165647963666326">
                <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-32C491BB4DA90C1EBD165647963666327">
                    <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-32C491BB4DA90C1EBD165647963666325" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
                </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </ds:Signature>
    </wsse:Security>
    <wsa:Action>http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:From>
        <wsa:Address>https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</wsa:Address>
    </wsa:From>
    <wsa:MessageID>uuid:84eacffc-0f1b-496a-bd0e-571a5d880aa7</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:To>http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</wsa:To>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body wsu:Id="id-32C491BB4DA90C1EBD165647963666328" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <v1:GetCheckResultRequest>
        <v11:RequestID>624f95e5-6a96-483f-b0b8-a483c49d7bee</v11:RequestID>
    </v1:GetCheckResultRequest>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My binding code:

```
private Binding GetCustomBinding2()
    {
        var secBE = SecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateBindingElement();

        /*

        var secBE = SecurityBindingElement.CreateCertificateOverTransportBindingElement();
        // ERRO00001: XPath expression /*[local-name()='Envelope']/*[local-name()='Body'] not covered by signature
            
        var secBE = SecurityBindingElement.CreateAnonymousForCertificateBindingElement();
        var secBE = SecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateBindingElement();
        // ERRO00001 *The Verification Type configuration 'asymmetric' does not allow algorithm 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1'*

        The servive provider wants the signature signed with rsa-sha1
        ... but his algorithm suite doesn't exist in .NET anymore ??
                    
        var secBE = SecurityBindingElement.CreateCertificateSignatureBindingElement();
        // Exception:  contract only supports the OneWay operation
                    
        var secBE = SecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateDuplexBindingElement();
        // ERRO00001: The request could not be accepted because it failed to be authenticated

        */


        TextMessageEncodingBindingElement textEncBE = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement
        {
            MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap12WSAddressingAugust2004,
            WriteEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
        };

        HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsBE = new HttpsTransportBindingElement
        {
            RequireClientCertificate = true
        };

        var myBinding = new CustomBinding();
        myBinding.Elements.Add(secBE);
        myBinding.Elements.Add(textEncBE);
        myBinding.Elements.Add(httpsBE);

        return myBinding;
    }
```

The SOAP produced by my code (which gets error response):

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_4">http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</a:Action>
    <a:From u:Id="_5">
        <a:Address>https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</a:Address>
    </a:From>
    <a:MessageID u:Id="_6">urn:uuid:60b141dd-4b5c-4647-ba8d-1fa008f6e0de</a:MessageID>
    <ActivityId CorrelationId="b6dcd628-083b-41f3-ae23-99297c462fe0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">4fc61092-3f74-4eb6-96b7-ec9d5fc9ea15</ActivityId>
    <a:ReplyTo u:Id="_7">
        <a:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_8">https://nss-ws-train.acic.gov.au/nss-ws/CheckResultRetrieval</a:To>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <u:Timestamp u:Id="uuid-25cd3298-de48-48db-9817-e2917bdc6999-2">
            <u:Created>2022-07-01T00:38:35.634Z</u:Created>
            <u:Expires>2022-07-01T00:43:35.634Z</u:Expires>
        </u:Timestamp>
        <e:EncryptedKey Id="uuid-25cd3298-de48-48db-9817-e2917bdc6999-1" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
            <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p">
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"></DigestMethod>
            </e:EncryptionMethod>
            <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                    <o:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#ThumbprintSHA1">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</o:KeyIdentifier>
                </o:SecurityTokenReference>
            </KeyInfo>
            <e:CipherData>
                <e:CipherValue>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</e:CipherValue>
            </e:CipherData>
        </e:EncryptedKey>
        <c:DerivedKeyToken u:Id="_0" xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/02/sc">
            <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                <o:Reference URI="#uuid-25cd3298-de48-48db-9817-e2917bdc6999-1"></o:Reference>
            </o:SecurityTokenReference>
            <c:Offset>0</c:Offset>
            <c:Length>24</c:Length>
            <c:Nonce>
                <!-- Removed-->
            </c:Nonce>
        </c:DerivedKeyToken>
        <o:BinarySecurityToken>
            <!-- Removed-->
        </o:BinarySecurityToken>
        <Signature Id="_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo>
                <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></CanonicalizationMethod>
                <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1"></SignatureMethod>
                <Reference URI="#_3">
                    <Transforms>
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></Transform>
                    </Transforms>
                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></DigestMethod>
                    <DigestValue>vbETU40K2domiAcXqpzYTQ437EY=</DigestValue>
                </Reference>
                <Reference URI="#_4">
                    <Transforms>
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></Transform>
                    </Transforms>
                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></DigestMethod>
                    <DigestValue>PyYM/+DKjoRYkl7vU1lKJPiRuw8=</DigestValue>
                </Reference>
                <Reference URI="#_5">
                    <Transforms>
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></Transform>
                    </Transforms>
                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></DigestMethod>
                    <DigestValue>R0gx/VuYg6cr+gLizmfhPDLsoVM=</DigestValue>
                </Reference>
                <Reference URI="#_6">
                    <Transforms>
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></Transform>
                    </Transforms>
                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></DigestMethod>
                    <DigestValue>mLvPIB+nD1Pb4QgC8rlSiP+qNY4=</DigestValue>
                </Reference>
                <Reference URI="#_7">
                    <Transforms>
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></Transform>
                    </Transforms>
                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></DigestMethod>
                    <DigestValue>AEOH0t2KYR8mivgqUGDrgMtxgEQ=</DigestValue>
                </Reference>
                <Reference URI="#_8">
                    <Transforms>
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></Transform>
                    </Transforms>
                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></DigestMethod>
                    <DigestValue>FWeslFLS8iZvexCL1qCDVK1vgCY=</DigestValue>
                </Reference>
                <Reference URI="#uuid-25cd3298-de48-48db-9817-e2917bdc6999-2">
                    <Transforms>
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></Transform>
                    </Transforms>
                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></DigestMethod>
                    <DigestValue>zVaxtlzJdEfXOTATlPVnmWy+se4=</DigestValue>
                </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>wfxV8qPS7PlV4iwNJdcJCbXm4EQ=</SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
                <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                    <o:Reference URI="#_0"></o:Reference>
                </o:SecurityTokenReference>
            </KeyInfo>
        </Signature>
        <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo>
                <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></CanonicalizationMethod>
                <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"></SignatureMethod>
                <Reference URI="#_1">
                    <Transforms>
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></Transform>
                    </Transforms>
                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></DigestMethod>
                    <DigestValue>NllOt3h9JKZjTLRAkNz2WDoSAr0=</DigestValue>
                </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
                <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                    <o:Reference URI="#uuid-46c8f1fb-7662-4518-a329-664b8a2fc292-1"></o:Reference>
                </o:SecurityTokenReference>
            </KeyInfo>
        </Signature>
    </o:Security>
</s:Header>
<s:Body u:Id="_3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <GetCheckResultRequest xmlns="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">
        <RequestID xmlns="http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx">hello</RequestID>
    </GetCheckResultRequest>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: According to the documentation SHA1 should be disabled, maybe you can change to SHA2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65254733/how-do-i-properly-sign-a-soap-message-with-sha2-in-c

Comment: Not an option I'm afraid. The service provider requires it.

Comment: I'm having a bit more success building the SOAP from scratch and using a SignedXML. If I drop my .NET to 4.6.1 then RSA-SHA1 is being used. I'll post this as an answer "IF" I get it to "work".